# What logic operator to use, AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, logic

What operator or expression can I use that will fire on
every number, including zero?

I want a logic operator that will fire with ever
number it receives. My animations pause 
at zero.

This skips on zero

```
if (numberThing> 0);
```

This jitters 'fires quickly and goes back on count'

```
if (numberThing== 0);
```

---

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/logicTest.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/logicTest.jpg)

EXPLANATION
I'm catching split string values in a logic
function, and feeding them to a series of
IF, ELSE IF statements. I'm using this with a timer, so I can measure
the discrepancy.

Comment: if `numberThing` really is a numeric type, then why do you even need put it in an `if` statement?

Comment: @Kaleb, I've tried it without the IF statements. It doesn't receive the values properly if I just associate my tweens to the values I've split. It's barely noticeable in my animations, but I want it to be perfect.

Comment: See a similar question I resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747877/substrings-timer-and-led-lights-as3

Comment: Is that last else if supposed to set AlphaTween_ instead of AlphaTween__?

Comment: You're not phrasing your question meaningfully, and thus are unlikely to get an answer that helps. Clearly state: 1. what you want to accomplish, 2. what you've tried, and 3. what (incorrect) behavior the current non-working solution causes.

Comment: @Cory, better analysis and description next time. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `if (numberThing> 0 || numberThing === 0)`?

Comment: @Gabe, this worked. Also, if (numberThing> 0 || numberThing == 0)

Answer (score 3):

you could do

```
if(numberThing >= 0)
```

or if they are all numbers anyway

```
if(true)
```

kind of strange that it wouldn't just run with no if statements, is there anywhere else this issue could be coming from?

Comment: is there a chance that the problem is somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!isNaN(value))
```

Comment: I voted this up because it worked too, thanks (!isNaN(numberThing))